# How can I avoid overlap of colors if my UIViews border color alpha is less than 1.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, border, calayer

I have `UIView`'s alpha set at .5, and its border color alpha is .5 as well, they are a similar shade of gray, but it shows up as a thicker gray on the outside.  I am guessing this is because the two colors are being mixed together.  Is there a way that instead of just adding a border on top, I can add a border that will displace the pixels underneath it?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, the only way around this would be to place your 0.5 alpha view inside a container view and inset it slightly and add the border to the container.

Comment: That would solve it.  The only thing that would suck about that, is I have a rounded corner, so I would have to find the superviews radius, and calculate the radius of the subview, also using on the borderwidth.

Comment: You could subclass `UIView` and override [`drawRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView).

Comment: Or subclass UIView to add a CALayer that is one pixel bigger than it's view's layer, and has a borderColor and borderWidth as desired. For a one-off you could add code to your view controller that would add a layer to the view through code rather than subclassing UIView. I doubt if a single pixel increase in width would necessitate adjusting the corner radius, unless the view is VERY small.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to post this as an answer rather than a comment: 
An alternate approach would be to subclass UIView to add a CALayer that is one pixel bigger than it's view's layer, and has a borderColor and borderWidth as desired. For a one-off you could add code to your view controller that would add a layer to the view through code rather than subclassing UIView. I doubt if a single pixel increase in width would necessitate adjusting the corner radius, unless the view is VERY small. – Duncan C 37 secs ago  edit